# Help solving simultaneous equation with powers

Tags: linear-algebra, exponentiation

I am trying to solve the following equations:

$0.5 = exp(-(3*c)^k)$ and $0.99 = exp(-(29*c)^k)$

I have used MATLAB to get the answers of $c = 0.21487$ and $k = 0.83471$ but I'd really like to know the method if anybody has any idea how to do it?

Many thanks!

Comment: I think you may not be solving for your roots correctly in Matlab. If you plug your "solutions" back in to your equations, you'll see that they don't check out. Additionally, for problems like, these it's also helpful to indicate if your variables are really or complex and if you have any additional constraints (e.g., non-negative).

Comment: Hi guys, thank you all for your help! I appreciate it. When I plug the values I got from Matlab into the equation I get 0.5 and 0.99 as expected. When I use the ones given in the answer I get 0.5 and 0.01. I notice that 0.01 is 1-0.99 and 0.5 could also be 1-0.5. So I'm not sure which is correct?

Comment: Also, I expect the values of c and k to be positive or negative real numbers as they are coefficients in a calculation of wind speed using something called a Weibul distribution. Thanks again!

Comment: Either the equation in your question is wrong or it does not match what your code is then. Look closely. Probably a sign error.

Comment: You are right! I had made a mistake in my code! Thanks for your help!! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

taking the logarithm we get $-\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=(3c)^{k}$ and $-\ln(0.99)=(29c)^k$ and taking the logarithm again we have $$\ln\left(-\ln\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)=k\ln(3c)$$ and $$\ln(-\ln(0.99))=k\ln(29c)$$ now you can divide both equations to get $c$
i got the following solutions
$$c\approx 0.4056727050$$,$$k \approx -1.866120254$$

Comment: this answer looks a lot better.

Comment: yes you are right